# Can Retrofit support different versions of the same api in Android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, version

I have an Android app and I am using Retrofit to make http requests. Server side has come up with an updated version of the api. My app has to support both the old and new versions. Eg:

1. Old version: `https://api.company.com/abc/def/2018-01-01/add`
2. New version: `https://api.company.com/abc/def/2019-01-01/add`

My BASE_URL is: `https://api.company.com`.

My question is, what is the best way to support both the versions in Retrofit. The decision to whether use old or new version is made at the runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you pass parameter the api version to retrofit interface method?

Comment: I thought about it but its a big app with lot of apis, which will mean updating a lot of code. Hence, decided against it. Is there a smart way to use it as a path parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with the path and your interface

```
@GET("abc/def/{version}/add")
    Call<List<String>> getFilterValues(@Path(value = "version", encoded = true))
```

version will then get put into the url where you have `{version}`

Usage example

```
String version = "2018-01-01";

if(useNewVersion){
    version = "2019-01-01";
}

Call<List<String>> call = api.getFilterValues(version);
```

Comment: But isn't that version required to be constant? I have to decide the version at runtime.

Comment: @tyczi make `@GET("/abc/def/{version}/add")
    Call<List<String>> getFilterValues(@Path(value = "version", encoded = true) String path)` bcoz retrofit getting base url end with `/` in retrofit client.

Comment: @Kanika make `https://api.company.com/` is constant. and others part use as dynamic URL. It is good practice and if your app goes from debug to development then you have to change only domain name other things would be same.

Comment: @Kanika who said it is required to be constant? That path value is just a parameter you pass in like anything else.

I edited my answer with usage example

Answer (score 0):

Here is extended variation of the above answer, but imo it will also be difficult if too many endpoints:

```
@GET
Single<JsonResponse> getSomething(@Url String url);


String requestUrl = "....";
restApiService.getSomething(requestUrl);
```